Unable to connect to RPi AP
I am trying to build my home router using the Raspberry Pi 3B+. I wish to learn more about routers and experiment with them. I am using a Tp-Link AC1300 T3U WiFi Dongle as an external NIC card with the Pi.
I configured the hostapd, DHCP, dnsmasq and enabled masquerading through "sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE"
When I reboot the pi or the service, it broadcasts the SSID, and when I enter the password, it gets stuck on "connecting...". After a few seconds, it doesn't connect but the SSID is still discoverable.
Here are my hostapd.conf
    country_code=IN
    interface=wlan0
    ssid=SSID
    hw_mode=g
    channel=7
    macaddr_acl=0
    auth_algs=1
    ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
    wpa=2
    wpa_passphrase=PWD
    wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    wpa_pairwise=TKIP
    rsn_pairwise=CCMP```

Here is my dnsmaq.conf
    interface=wlan0
    dhcp-range=192.168.4.2,192.168.4.20,255.255.255.0,24h
    domain=wlan
    address=/gw.wlan/192.168.4.1

Here is my dhcpcd.conf
    interface wlan0
    static ip_address=192.168.4.1/24
    nohook wpa_supplicant

[Edit] OS details
    PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
    NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
    VERSION_ID="12"
    VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
    VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
    ID=debian
    HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
    SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
    BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

kernel details
    Linux raspberrypi 6.6.31+rpt-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 
    1:6.6.31-1+rpt1 (2024-05-29) aarch64 GNU/Linux

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

@Milliways here are the OS details "Linux raspberrypi 6.6.31+rpt-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.6.31-1+rpt1 (2024-05-29) aarch64 GNU/Linux
"

my bad, it is bookworm actually, what are my alternatives?
PS I have edited the question too

This question is similar to: How do I set up networking on Raspberry Pi OS - Bookworm. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
